# How to classify words in groups

Tags: classification

I have a problem when I need to classify words in groups.
For example:
Input: apple, watermelon, knife, soap.

I need to split the input in groups

Food: apple, watermelon
Object: knife
Cleaning Product: Soap

But I don't know the best approach to do my objective.
Has anyone else ever had a similar problem?

Comment: If you've a fix number of groups you can start from any classification method related to your features.

Comment: And if not that can be done with semi-supervised approaches, for example.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use pretrained word embeddings like word2vec (https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/21/the-amazing-power-of-word-vectors/), which map a word to a real-valued vector in a high-dimensional space, and then use clustering techniques (k-means, etc.) to assign words to categories.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a classification problem and like you already know the correct classes. So I guess that you are asking for a supervised method from the area of Machine Learning (ML).

To find some ideas about ML in general and get some method you can have a look at the paper [A Few Useful Things to Know about ML](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2347755).

Beside simpler methods you could have a look to implementations of neural networks. In the paper [Convolutional Neural Networks for Sentence Classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5882.pdf), but be aware that they classify for sentiments and also have whole sentences as input.

Moreover, there are also projects with an API available, which give you a class for a given word. I am not able to remember one. Maybe some other user know more about that.